# Query is not matching multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Thought this MySQL query was working and is returning results but it is 
disregarding the bit:  where published='1' part and showing all results
regardless of what the value of published is.

I think it has something to do with having brackets around certain bits of 
the query but have tried it various ways and don't seem to be able to get
it right.

Here is how I have the query at the moment:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE published='1' 
  AND title LIKE '%$q%' 
   OR details LIKE '%$q%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply explicit parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE published='1'
  AND (title LIKE '%$q%' OR details LIKE '%$q%')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

In your example with implicit parenthesis it was working like that:

```
WHERE (published='1' AND title LIKE '%$q%')
   OR details LIKE '%$q%'
```

Because `and` has a higher evaluation precedence than `or`.

Comment: Thanks very much - and for the explanation - appreciated! Thought I had tried that but obviously not as it is now working as it should - apologies as it makes sense